# How navbar and footer make fixed in react

Tags: reactjs, react-router

i have a question about how keep navbar and footer components stable on route change, now when i change route, so when i click some page from navbar all page refreshing with navbar and footer.

i think somewhere i make a mistake.

here is my app component:

```
class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Router>
        <div>
          <Navbar/>
          <main>
            <Switch>
              <Route exact path='/' component={Home}/>
              <Route path='/Whoweare' component={Whoweare}/>
              <Route path='/Solution' component={Solution}/>
              <Route path='/ContactUs' component={ContactUs}/>
            </Switch>
          </main>
          <Footer/>
        </div>
      </Router>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

i place here navbar and footer outside of router Switch tag it's right, not?

It's navbar component:

```
import React from 'react';
import {Navbar, Nav, Button, Container, NavItem} from 'react-bootstrap';
const NavbarComp = () =>
        <Navbar>
            <Container>
                <Navbar.Brand href="/">Logo</Navbar.Brand>
                <Navbar.Toggle />
                <Navbar.Collapse className="justify-content-end">
                    <Nav>
                        <NavItem>
                            <Nav.Link href='/Whoweare'>Who we are</Nav.Link>
                        </NavItem>
                        <NavItem>
                            <Nav.Link href='/Solution'>Solution</Nav.Link>
                        </NavItem>
                    </Nav>
                </Navbar.Collapse>
            </Container>
        </Navbar>

export default NavbarComp;
```

Comment: Please share your navbar code for better understanding of the redirection

Comment: @Help updated answer with navbar component

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure about the react bootstrap integration with react router dom.

Ideally you should be using `Link` from `react-router-dom`

so in your navbar `import { Link } from 'react-router-dom'`

and in change your `NavItem`to

```
<NavItem>
     <Link to='/Solution'>Solution</Link>
</NavItem>
```

This will not refresh the page but instead update the component (view)

Hope this is helps you. :)

Comment: Glad to help :)

Answer (score 0):

I think you should place the navbar and the footer outside of the router, that way those will always be there even when you change routes. I think this is what you are looking for?